# Aurelia's Component Not Being Replace By Its Template

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Why dont Aurelia's custom elements get replace by its template, instead of being put inside it?

Example:
**I want this**

```
<sidebar-item label="Dashboard" href="#" icon="icon-home4"></sidebar-item>
```

**to be replaced by this**

```
<li class="active">
     <a href="index.html">
          <i class="icon-home4"></i>
          <span>Dashboard</span>
     </a>
</li>
```

**but instead, the result is this:**

```
<sidebar-item label="Dashboard" href="#" icon="icon-home4">
       <li class="active">
            <a href="index.html"><i class="icon-home4"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a>
       </li>
</sidebar-item>
```

Is there a way to replace the custom tag for its template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically add `@containerless` to the view-model of `SidebarItem`.

```
import {containerless} from 'aurelia-framework';

@containerless
export class SidebarItem {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Based in your answer, i found one specific attribute to put in the HTML component tag, because my component is HTML only, and to put the decorator @containerless, i would have to create a new JS file, instead i did this:

`<sidebar-item containerless></sidebar-item>`

Comment: You can't have a containerless component with an HTML only component. It is a limitation of the HTML only component.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately i can't add a comment to ZoolWay above but just to add to that you will need to import 'containerless' from 'aurelia-framework' iirc

Comment: I added an example for you.